# Storing Data from a txt file into a map with two keys java

Tags: java, maps

I was wondering how you go about storing data from a text file into a map.

Fulham : Leeds United : 1 : 2

Wigan Athletic : Tottenham Hotspur : 2 : 5

Hull City : Everton : 3 : 1

I would like to be able to store each team then also be able to work out: goals scored, goals conceded and so on. I cant seem to implement a map with multiple keys.Below is what i have so far.

public void totalGames()
        {

```
        File inputfile = new File ("validtest.txt.txt");
        try{

            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            //Map<String[], int[]> teams = new Map<>();
            HashMap<String,String> teamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(filescan.hasNext()){
            //  StrArray = aLine.split(separator);


                String[] teamKey = filescan.nextLine().split(" : ");


                teamMap.put(teamKey[0], teamKey[1]);





                }
            filescan.close();
            System.out.println(teamMap);

                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){


                }
```

this outputs.
{Tottenham Hotspur=Stoke City, Fulham=Leeds United}

whereas i would like too have:

{fulham=1 Leeds united = 2}

Could anyone point me in the right direction new to this.

Comment: Your description makes no sense, as you seem to be using `teamName`, `TeamName` and `score` as placeholders for all kinds of different things.  Just add a sample line from your file, the output you are getting from it, and what you would like to get.

Comment: A Team is an object: name, goals scored, goals received, matches won, drawn, lost. A Match is another object: teamname-1, teamname-2, scored-1, scored-2. Read data, create Match objects. Create Teams. Process Match objects by updating Team goals and match results.

Comment: they were just for an example of the text file I have updated it .

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this. Do you have match as a key and team as a key in the map ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Guava has a Solution using Table Data Structure [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps)

```
Table<String, String, Integer[]> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put(String,String,Integer[]);
table.get(String,String);
```